# Error while scraping the page, Cloud Flare protection, cookies

Tags: php, curl, cookies, cloudflare

I would like to download data from https://ucp.paradise-rpg.pl/group/684
I was able to make such a code in CURL, it works correctly on other websites and on https://ucp.paradise-rpg.pl/group/684 such an error pops up from cloudflare, what should I do?

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kA5hp.png)

```
<?php

$lurl=get_fcontent("https://ucp.paradise-rpg.pl/%22);
print_r($lurl[0]);


function get_fcontent( $url,  $javascript_loop = 0, $timeout = 5 ) {
    $url = str_replace( "&amp;", "&", urldecode(trim($url)) );

    $cookie = tempnam ("/tmp", "CURLCOOKIE");
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla / 5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv: 31.0) Gecko / 20100101 Firefox / 31.0");
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "" );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );    # required for https urls
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $timeout );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10 );
    $content = curl_exec( $ch );
    $response = curl_getinfo( $ch );
    curl_close ( $ch );

    if ($response['http_code'] == 301  $response['http_code'] == 302) {
        ini_set("user_agent", "Mozilla / 5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv: 31.0) Gecko / 20100101 Firefox / 31.0");

        if ( $headers = get_headers($response['url']) ) {
            foreach( $headers as $value ) {
                if ( substr( strtolower($value), 0, 9 ) == "location:" )
                    return get_url( trim( substr( $value, 9, strlen($value) ) ) );
            }
        }
    }

    if (    ( preg_match("/>[[:space:]]+window.location.replace('(.*)')/i", $content, $value)  preg_match("/>[[:space:]]+window.location="(.*)"/i", $content, $value) ) && $javascript_loop < 5) {
        return get_url( $value[1], $javascript_loop+1 );
    } else {
        return array( $content, $response );
    }
}

    ?>
```

Comment: One of CloudFlare's major features is preventing this sort of thing. It's quite hard to get around, and they update it regularly to lock down new techniques. Ask the site owner if they have an API.

Comment: I get a api https://ucp.paradise-rpg.pl/api/group/637 do you write to me simple script in PHP which display data on the page?

Comment: No, I will not write your code for you. Glad you found an API.

Comment: and you could guide me at least what should I do?